# Is the current in the correct direction in this image describing a one phase generator?

Tags: motor, electromagnetism, generator, induction, synchronous-motor

The dot on the left is current going towards us according to the image. But if the magnet is rotating counter clockwise while the conductor is stationary (which is same as magnet being stationary while the conductor rotates clockwise), I would expect the current to be in the opposite direction, that is away from us on the left side and towards us on the right side. Is that right?

[image]

Image above "describes" the following. If the current is wrong above then so is the induced voltage \$e\$ below:

[image]

Comment: If that's not your drawing or design then you need to credit it. (This is [site policy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).) Hit the [edit] link ...

Comment: You are referring to an article on how to properly *answer* a question and not to one about asking a question.

Comment: The principle is the same. Credit the author of the work.

Comment: You have to check to see how the book (or whatever source) references "current." Is it "conventional current" or "electron Current" in the rest of the text.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it violates site policy requiring the author or source of works, not one's own, to be properly credited.

Comment: This is not a public work and I have decided against posting and shaming this author of these images as this seems to be wrong. I still dont see any rule that says that there has to be a source in a question. You can go back and see my other posts as I usually post the source of the content but in this case I decide against.

Comment: @ScienceGeyser, this is conventional current aka. positive charges since we see where the induced voltage e has its positive terminal and hence draw the conclusion where the current is heading in the top image.

Comment: It seems correct for conventional current. Right hand rule for generators, left hand rule for motors.

Comment: @ScienceGeyser, thanks for the reply. So, as this is a generator I apply the RHR. If we take the conductor on the left side then the thumb points up in the direction the wire is crossing the field lines. The index finger points in the direction towards the south pole so it is to the right. The middle finger then points away from us and has the opposite direction than that of the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP @clone is correct in saying the diagrams do not represent a generator. Curling the fingers of the right hand around the wire, with the thumb pointing in the direction of current flow *assuming a generator* results in the contradiction of the magnetic field being reinforced on the leading side of the rotor, not the trailing side. The contradiction means the original assumption was incorrect, and that the diagrams show a motor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!